# How to solve this generic intermittent SSL error?

Tags: ssl, iis, curl

I'm getting a cURL error when my website attempts to retrieve data from the CRM.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'cURL Error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to dev.company.com:444' in CRMDConnector\DynamicsCRM2011_Connector.class.php:1177
```

I'm also getting this error, but its more specific to the php library I'm using.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not find Port for trust type <UserNameWSTrustBinding_IWSTrust13Async> in provided WSDL' in CRMDConnector\DynamicsCRM2011_Connector.class.php:650
```

This is the library, for reference: https://github.com/Rocketeer007/php-dynamics-crm-2011/blob/master/DynamicsCRM2011_Connector.class.php

The interesting part is that sometimes there is no error and everything works fine, but sometimes it gives these errors and fails to show the content on the page.

Any ideas or requests for specific information to help further diagnose the issue?

I have a suspicion that the IIS and Apache being on the same server may be causing the problem, although I don't know why it would be intermittent instead of constant. IIS redirects requests on ports 80 and 443 to Apache and requests on port 444 go to the CRM.

I've tried forcing IPV4 connections, as per [this](https://blogs.agilefaqs.com/2013/11/25/curl-35-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-in-connection/) post, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows SSL Cipher Suite Order was the culprit:
http://cloud365.in/tls-protocol-defined-fatal-error-code-is-20-schannel-error-state-is-960/